# Как удалить элементы { } : " " и буквы U S D. Все это надо сделать на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, requests

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
import requests
from config import token

bot = Bot(token=token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет!\nКоманды:\n/btc - курс биткоина\n/eth - курс эфиримуа\n/doge - курс догикоина\n/ltc - курс лайткоина")

@dp.message_handler(commands=['btc'])
async def btc(message: types.Message):
    response = requests.get(url="https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD")
    await message.reply(response.text)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['eth'])
async def eth(message: types.Message):
    response = requests.get(url="https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD")
    print(response.text)
    await message.reply(response.text)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['doge'])
async def eth(message: types.Message):
    response = requests.get(url="https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=DOGE&tsyms=USD")
    print(response.text)
    await message.reply(response.text)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['ltc'])
async def eth(message: types.Message):
    response = requests.get(url="https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=LTC&tsyms=USD")
    print(response.text)
    await message.reply(response.text)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: Мне кажется для асинхронного бота лучше использовать асихронную библиотеку для запросов по сети. Если у той библиотеки не будет аналога `json` как у `requests`, то парсите ответ через встроенную библиотеку `json`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно не парсить текст, а обработать ответ как `JSON`, т.к. сайт его и возвращает

Действия:

- Через метод `json` парсите ответ
- Вытаскиваете данные по ключу

Пример:

```
import requests

rs = requests.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD')
print(rs.text)  # Как текст
# {"USD":42193.22}

print(rs.json())  # Как распарсенный JSON
# {'USD': 42193.22}

print(rs.json()['USD'])
# 42191.13
```

Можно вытащить значение словаря и без ключа:

```
print(list(rs.json().values())[0])
# 42191.13
```

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю вам нужно это:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['btc'])
async def btc(message: types.Message):
    response = requests.get(url="https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD")
    result = response.text.replace("{", "") # Заменяем символ { на воздух
    await message.reply(result)
```